# ERROR: syntax error at or near "and"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like this.

```
select 
  ad.escore,
  ad.mscore,
  round(sum(ps.cnt) / sum(n.cnt) * 100,1) as percent
from 
(
  select 
    account_no,
    -- 602 becomes '595-604'
    to_char(trunc(empirica_score - 5, -1) + 5, '9999') || '-' || to_char(trunc(empirica_score - 5, -1) + 14, '9999') as escore,
    -- 97 becomes '76-100'. Change the expression to group differently.
    cast(((mfin_score - 1) / 25) * 25 + 1 as text) || '-' || cast(((mfin_score - 1) / 25) * 25 + 25 as text) as mscore
  from account_details
) ad
join 
(
  select custno, count(*) as cnt
  from paysoft_results 
  where result = 'Successful' 
  and resultdate >= '13/08/2014'     <------- HERE
  and resultdate <= '12/19/2014'     <------- HERE
  group by custno
) ps on ps.custno = ad.account_no
join 
(
  select customer_code, count(distinct start_date) as cnt
  from naedo 
  and start_date >= '13/08/2014'      <------- HERE
  and start_date <= '12/19/2014'      <------- HERE
  group by customer_code
) n on n.customer_code = ad.account_no
group by ad.escore, ad.mscore;
```

It works perfect if I dont have the date installed like above.

if I do put in the dates i get a error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "and"`

Any ideas why?

**UPDATE**

Okay, i suppose I can ask a now question, so if I can append on this one.

`ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "13/08/2014"`

the date comparison in my query. What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: morne, the update probably should have been a _new_ question but I've covered it in an aside to my original answer.

Comment: Do **not** rely on implicit data type conversion. Always use a proper date literal, rather than a string constant. `'13/08/2014'` is a string, not a date. You should either use Oracle's to_date() function: `to_date('13/08/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY')` or (a bit shorter) an ANSI date literal: `date '2014-08-13'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, *this* bit won't work:

```
select customer_code, count(distinct start_date) as cnt
from naedo 
and start_date >= '13/08/2014'      <------- HERE
and start_date <= '12/19/2014'      <------- HERE
group by ...
```

since the `where` clause has to start with a `where`, not an `and`. Otherwise, we'd all be calling it an `and` clause :-)

It'll need to be:

```
select customer_code, count(distinct start_date) as cnt
from naedo 
where start_date >= '13/08/2014'
  and start_date <= '12/19/2014'
group by ...
```

The other bit you've marked with `HERE` (the second segment, first `join` clause) looks fine, it should work without error.

---

As an aside, at least *one* of your dates is in the incorrect format. The segment:

```
and start_date >= '13/08/2014'
and start_date <= '12/19/2014'
```

either has a date of the 8<sup>th</sup> of Undecimber or the 12<sup>th</sup> of, well, I don't even *know* what the Latin prefix for nineteen (or seventeen based on the real months already being out of step) is.

You'll need to figure out which of `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy` your database supports and then stick with just that *one.*

Given that you question update states it's complaining about `13/08/2014`, you'll probably find it should be written as `08/13/2014`, in `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

Comment: facePalm ... yes just noticed.

Answer (score 1):

```
    select customer_code, count(distinct start_date) as cnt
      from naedo 
      Where start_date >= '13/08/2014'      <------- HERE
      and start_date <= '12/19/2014'      <------- HERE
      group by customer_code
```

Answer (score 1):

"Where " missing in query:

```
"    select customer_code, count(distinct start_date) as cnt
      from naedo where
      start_date >= '13/08/2014'      <------- HERE"
"
============================
select 
      ad.escore,
      ad.mscore,
      round(sum(ps.cnt) / sum(n.cnt) * 100,1) as percent
    from 
    (
      select 
        account_no,
        -- 602 becomes '595-604'
        to_char(trunc(empirica_score - 5, -1) + 5, '9999') || '-' || to_char(trunc(empirica_score - 5, -1) + 14, '9999') as escore,
        -- 97 becomes '76-100'. Change the expression to group differently.
        cast(((mfin_score - 1) / 25) * 25 + 1 as text) || '-' || cast(((mfin_score - 1) / 25) * 25 + 25 as text) as mscore
      from account_details
    ) ad
    join 
    (
      select custno, count(*) as cnt
      from paysoft_results 
      where result = 'Successful' 
      and resultdate >= '13/08/2014'     <------- HERE
      and resultdate <= '12/19/2014'     <------- HERE
      group by custno
    ) ps on ps.custno = ad.account_no
    join 
    (
      select customer_code, count(distinct start_date) as cnt
      from naedo where
      start_date >= '13/08/2014'      <------- HERE
      and start_date <= '12/19/2014'      <------- HERE
      group by customer_code
    ) n on n.customer_code = ad.account_no
    group by ad.escore, ad.mscore;
```